# ずつ meaning clarification

Tags: words

I just need a little clarification on the use of ずつ. Since its meaning is "at a time", let's take a look at the following sentence:

> 2回並んで、1枚ずつ整理券をもらった。

So this means that you got on line twice, and for each time, you received a registered ticket (so in the end, you would have two registered tickets, one for each time). Is this correct? Can someone please give some more examples of how ずつ is used?

Comment: http://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%9A%E3%81%A4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**On your sentence**

Your understanding is correct. You queued twice, and got one ticket each time.

```
2回並んで、1枚ずつ整理券をもらった。
I queued twice and got one ticket each time.

2回並んで、1枚整理券をもらった。
I queued twice and got (only) one ticket.

2回並んで、整理券をもらった。
I queued twice and got a positive, indefinite, amount of tickets.
```

That being said, in a very contrived context, the following could be correct:

```
2回並んで、1枚ずつ整理券をもらった。
I queued twice and got several tickets, each time one at a time.
```

However, while technically possible, this would be extremely unlikely as it is all but natural and clear.

**On ずつ**

Here are some examples.

```
～にAとBを大さじ1杯ずつ加える
add a tablespoon each of A and B to ~

～を1個ずつ箱に詰める
pack ~ into the box one by one

～を半分ずつにする
split ~ 50-50

一人ずつ順番に尋ねる
ask each in turn
```

Answer (score 3):

ずつ means something like "each" or "per X unit" or as you said "at a time". The counter before ずつ describes the exact number of parts you have to take out of a big group of similar things.

> - １枚ずつ = (for) each ticket / sheet of paper
> - [二人]{ふたり}ずつ並んでください。 = Line up by 2 people.
> - 少しずつ = step by step