# How can I ask for "two of each" (cream and sugar) at a cafe?

Tags: translation, word-choice

I've had some trouble communicating I want '2 of each' or '2 more of each' at cafes.
It happens when I order a coffee and receive one stick of sugar and one creamer and I try to ask for 2 more by saying ２つもうお願いします but then I just receive 1 more of each.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ずつ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38359/5010).

> もう2つずつお願いします。

Note that もう must be placed *before* the number, and ずつ must be placed *after* the counter.

Comment: What happens when もう or ずつ is out of place? Would counterexamples help make the explanation more obvious?

Comment: @Flaw What do you mean by "out of place"? If ずつ comes before the number, it's simply ungrammatical. もう has various meanings and may happen to mean something else, but if you want to say "*another* two", もう always has to be before the number.

Comment: I had incorrectly thought that by changing the order of the words, the end result may be different instead of just being ungrammatical. Or I was trying to pre-empt the question "what would happen if I don't follow the order as explained in the answer?"